# Suspending Threads while Debugging Java Application IntelliJ

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea, java-threads

I'm debugging a multi-threaded Java application in IntelliJ. I want to suspend all threads on some breakpoint and resume only selected thread while I step-over the code. I can suspend all threads on a breakpoint, but when I step-over the code from one thread, others are also running. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Hmm, if you set a breakpoint, then all threads should still stop there.  Does that not work?

Comment: All threads are suspending when a thread reaches the breakpoint. But, when I step-over and analyze the code, the rest of the threads are also resuming.

Comment: OK, that's a bit odd, but I can see how it might happen.  In my debugger (not Intelij unfortunately) there's a separate window that I can manually suspend and resume threads (and inspect their call stack).  Can you do that on your system?  Alternately, when debugging, can you launch only one thread?

Comment: I can see a window summarizing all the threads. https://ibb.co/x3VBwWR

Comment: You can try to set up the following [breakpoint settings](https://prnt.sc/sosqic) and select the necessary thread via the [debug tool window](https://prnt.sc/sosrij).

Comment: @EgorKlepikov - Thanks for the help. But, doing so would suspend only one thread (the thread that reached the breakpoint). I want to be able to debug the thread that reached the breakpoint while others are suspended

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a setting exactly for this here:
Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Stepping - Resume only the current thread

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I wanted.